# How do i send delayed message in rabbitmq using the rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, rabbitmq-exchange

i have enabled the plugin using

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

I am trying to create delayed exchange and attached header x-delay with 5000ms as int value and binded it to a queue it dint work.

So i tried it using Pika in python:

```
import pika
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', 'admin')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost',5672,'/',credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='127.0.0.1',port=5673,credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
#channel.exchange_declare(exchange='x-delayed-type', type='direct')
channel.exchange_declare("test-exchange", type="x-delayed-message", arguments={"x-delayed-type":"direct"},durable=True,auto_delete=True)


channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue',durable=True)
channel.queue_bind(queue="task_queue", exchange="test-exchange", routing_key="task_queue")
for i in range(0,100):
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='test-exchange', routing_key='task_queue',
                          body='gooogle',
                          properties=pika.BasicProperties(headers={"x-delay": 5000},delivery_mode=1))
    print i
```

How can i make delayed exchange using delay make working?

Error Report :

```
ERROR REPORT==== 10-Mar-2017::13:08:09 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.683.0> (127.0.0.1:42052 -> 127.0.0.1:5673, vhost: '/', user: 'admin', state: running), channel 1:
{{{undef,
      [{erlang,system_time,[milli_seconds],[]},
       {rabbit_delayed_message,internal_delay_message,4,
           [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,179}]},
       {rabbit_delayed_message,handle_call,3,
           [{file,"src/rabbit_delayed_message.erl"},{line,122}]},
       {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,585}]},
       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},
  {gen_server,call,
      [rabbit_delayed_message,
       {delay_message,
           {exchange,
               {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"test-exchange">>},
               'x-delayed-message',true,true,false,
               [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"direct">>}],
               undefined,undefined,
               {[],[]}},
           {delivery,false,false,<0.691.0>,
               {basic_message,
                   {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"test-exchange">>},
                   [<<"task_queue">>],
                   {content,60,
                       {'P_basic',undefined,undefined,
                           [{<<"x-delay">>,signedint,5000}],
                           1,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                           undefined},
                       <<48,0,0,0,0,13,7,120,45,100,101,108,97,121,73,0,0,19,
                         136,1>>,
                       rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                       [<<"gooogle">>]},
                   <<80,125,217,116,181,47,214,41,203,179,7,85,150,76,35,2>>,
                   false},
               undefined,noflow},
           5000},
       infinity]}},
 [{gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,188}]},
  {rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,route,2,
      [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},{line,53}]},
  {rabbit_exchange,route1,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,381}]},
  {rabbit_exchange,route,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,371}]},
  {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
      [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,949}]},
  {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,457}]},
  {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1032}]},
  {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
```

Comment: Can you tell me which rabbitmq version you have?

Comment: {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.6"},

Answer (score 0):

Paste a workable code with Rabbitmq 3.7.7:

send.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

#channel.exchange_declare(exchange='direct_logs',
#                         exchange_type='direct')

#channel.exchange_declare("test-exchange", type="x-delayed-message", arguments={"x-delayed-type":"direct"},durable=True,auto_delete=True)
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='test-exchange',
                         exchange_type='x-delayed-message',
                         arguments={"x-delayed-type":"direct"})


severity = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 'info'
message = ' '.join(sys.argv[2:]) or 'Hello World!'
channel.basic_publish(exchange='test-exchange',
                      routing_key=severity,
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                          headers={'x-delay': 5000} # Add a key/value header
                      ),
                      body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r:%r" % (severity, message))
connection.close()
```

receive.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='test-exchange',
                         exchange_type='x-delayed-message',
                         arguments={"x-delayed-type":"direct"})

result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

binding_keys = sys.argv[1:]
if not binding_keys:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s [binding_key]...\n" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

for binding_key in binding_keys:
    channel.queue_bind(exchange='test-exchange',
                       queue=queue_name,
                       routing_key=binding_key)

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

python send.py error aaaabbbb

python receive.py error

```
 [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C    
 [x] 'error':'aaaabbbb'
```